# myBatis insert not null values conditionally

Tags: mysql, mybatis, ibatis

I want to insert not null values only if it is null. If null, let the DB insert the default values.

```
<insert id ="inventorySave">
<[CDATA[

INSET INTO inventory  
(itemname,amount,id,level) 
values
]]
<foreach item="inventory" collection="inventoryies" separator=",">
<[CDATA[
(#{inventory.itemName},#{inventory.amount}, #{inventory.id}, #{inventory.level})
]]
</foreach>
</insert>
```

I want to check the value for 'level' is a valid string: 'ordinary','important','severe'. If it has empty string or null, this should not be specify any and let the database decide to insert its default value.

Anyone let me know to how to conditionally insert records.

Answer (score 1):

Give all the dymanic values their equivalent **jdbcType**  i.e. **database column type** to acheive what you expect.

for example from your above query change as below for `level` and similarly for other entities:

```
    #{inventory.level,jdbcType=NVARCHAR} 
    //assuming the equivalent column type in database for itemname is varchar.
```